# Read (query) transaction flow in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: transactions, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to understand the "Query" transaction flow in Hyperledger Fabric. I understand the "write" flow in Fabric as it is well documented. However, things are not so clear when a read/query transaction is involved.

This is what I have understood so far:

1. A client using an SDK prepares a transaction proposal for querying a chaincode.
2. The proposal is transmitted via a committing peer to the Endorsing peers which validate as well as simulate the transaction in their end. Assuming everything is successful, the endorsing peers return their endorsements for the proposal. Each endorsement contains, among other things, a **readset** of the world state. Since this is just a query transaction, a **writeset** is not added inside each ensorsement. Is my understanding correct here?
3. Once the client receives the required amount of endorsement, it prepares a transaction which is sent to the Orderer.

I am not so sure of the flow after this. A write transaction is understandable: the order, after carrying out some checks, will create a block and propagate the block to all peers connected to the corresponding channel. All peers will append the block in the ledger after carrying out the validation of all transactions in the block, this essentially updates the ledger.

But what about a read transaction? What does the orderer will return upon receiving a read transaction? What will be the flow hereafter?

Any help or pointers will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/fabcar/query.js which demonstrates how to query using the Node SDK.  You'll notice that it uses the convenience method https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#queryByChaincode__anchor provided by the SDK to help facilitate queries.

In terms of the flow you outlined in your post, steps 1 and 2 are correct.
Additionally, chaincode functions which are intended for query transactions will typically use the https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#Success helper function to actually return the result of the query.  In the sample I posted above, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/fabcar/query.js#L51 invokes https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/chaincode/fabcar/fabcar.go#L135.

There is no need to send the responses from a query transaction to the orderer although you can as long as you meet the endorsement policy.  Thanks to Dave Enyeart for the following:

> A query is a chaincode invocation which reads the ledger current state
> but does
> not write to the ledger. The chaincode function may query certain keys on the ledger,
> or may query for a set of keys on the ledger. Since queries do not change ledger state,
> the client application will typically not submit these read-only transactions for ordering,
> validation, and committal. Although not typical, the client application can choose to
> submit the read-only transaction for ordering, validation, and commit, for example if the
> client wants auditable proof on the ledger chain that it had knowledge of specific ledger
> state at a certain point in time. Peers will validate and add the read-only transaction
> to the ledger chain, but there will be no updates to ledger current state.

Comment: Thanks Gari for the pointers. I have already looked into the Node SDK API and thought of something like what you mentioned as it resonated somewhat a similar concept in other blockchain platforms. However, what confused me was the official documentation where in the glossary page, it was mentioned this: "A transaction is an invoke or instantiate operation. Invokes are requests to read/write data from the ledger" Since a transaction can only be received by an orderer, then, when an order can receive a transaction with read data request? If never, the glossary might needs a correction. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Gari for the update from Dave. This now makes sense. I have seen the documentation has been updated as well. Hopefully this will clarify it for everyone.

Comment: I also have a doubt here, the query transaction(only read, no writes in chaincode function) either through the nodejs sdk (channel.queryByChaincode) or through the docker cli (available as part of fabcar exmaple or first n/w example) always generates a new block on the chain. If it is just a read, why is it creating a new block?

Comment: @Gari Singh Can you please look into my above comment?

Comment: The only way this could happen is if you submit the response from a query to the ordering service.  I do not believe that the SDKs do this by default.  For example, if you use the Node SDK and use the https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Channel.html#queryTransaction__anchor  function, this will not send anything to the ordering service

Answer (score 0):

This seems to contradict what you posted in your reply to this question:  [Roles (read+write) in hyperledger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017514/roles-readwrite-in-hyperledger)

The behavior you describe here makes sense,  whereas the behavior in the above answer seems totally broken.  Yet it seems that readers on a channel are not allowed to perform invokes.